How to change icon of button using setIcon in runtime/event/ in Android?
I was trying to create a button to switch night/light modes, to do so first I need to check the current /default mode of the user's device and set the button's icon and text accordingly, I tried to look up at internet and tried many solutions but it seems like icons are not changing at all.
here are the code snippets which I tried.
 val nightFlag = resources?.configuration?.uiMode?.and(Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK)
 if(nightFlag==16){
                mode.icon = (ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.darkmode))
                mode.text = "Night"
                recreate()
            }
            else{
                mode.icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.lightmode)
                mode.text = "Light"
                recreate()
            }

Another one
when (nightFlag) {
                Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> {
                    mode.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.lightmode))
                }

                Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> {
                    mode.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.darkmode))
               }

           }


nightFlag is giving correct answer '16' for light mode and '32' for dark mode in Logcat, now I'm completely confused why the icons aren't changing, please help. Thank you.

I think calling the recreate() might be the problem as it is causing activity to restart, which might be resetting your icon changes. Try removing the unnecessary calling of recreate().
Lastly, also check if R.drawable.lightmode and R.drawable.darkmode exists.
Hope this helps.

Hi, thank you for replying, i rechecked my whole code and it was misplaced '}', rip. Anyways thank you for your help.
